# CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy tratando de obtener datos de esta url:
http://carbono.utpl.edu.ec:8080/smartlandiotv2/webresources/entidades.datos/get?apikey=3bff8615827f32442199fdb2ed4df4

pero al momento de mostrar los resultados me sale este error:

Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://carbono.utpl.edu.ec:8080/smartlandiotv2/webresources/entidades.datos/get?apikey=3bff8615827f32442199fdb2ed4df4 (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

A continuación comparto mi código:

services.js

```
.service('ServEj', ['$http',function($http) {
    this.servicioEj = function() {
      return $http.get('http://carbono.utpl.edu.ec:8080/smartlandiotv2/webresources/entidades.datos/get?apikey=3bff8615827f32442199fdb2ed4df4');
    };
}])
```

controller.js

```
.controller('ctrl1',['$scope','ServEj','Autenticacion', function($scope, ServEj, Autenticacion){
    $scope.loader = true;
    ServEj.servicioEj().success(function(data){
        $scope.datos=data;
    })
    .error(function(data){
        $scope.Mensaje = 'Error de conexión..!';
    })
    .finally(function() {
    $scope.loader = false; 
    }); 

    $scope.salir = function(){
        Autenticacion.logout();
    }
}])
```

vista.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l9"></div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper indigo darken-1">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-field">
                      <input id="search" type="search" required ng-model="busqueda">
                      <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
                      <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="progress indigo lighten-3" ng-show="loader">
            <div class="indeterminate indigo darken-1"></div>
        </div>        
        <div class="collection" ng-show="Mensaje">
            <a class="collection-item indigo-text text-darken-3">
                {{Mensaje}}
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collection">
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item indigo-text text-darken-3" ng-repeat="i in datos | filter:busqueda">
                {{i.Nombre}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Quisiera saber como resolver este problema.

De antemano les agradezco.

Answer (score 3):

Bienvenido al apasionante mundo del [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Resumiendo: estás intentando acceder a un recurso alojado en un servidor A desde un recurso alojado por un servidor B, y por seguridad se exige que el servidor A autorice al B explícitamente.

El servidor A realiza esta autorización incluyendo este header al responderte: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (url del servidor B)`.

Así que para solucionar esto, hay que realizar una modificación en el servidor al que accedes para incluir ese header en sus respuestas.

Puedes ampliar información en [este artículo de la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Pero en el código que compartí como resuelvo mi problema porque he agregado headers pero me da el mismo error

Comment: ¿Dónde has agregado headers? Tienes que añadirlo a la respuesta del servidor, es decir, aquí: http://carbono.utpl.edu.ec:8080/smartlandiotv2/webresources/entidades.datos/get

Comment: si le estoy entendiendo el headers debo agregarlo en el servidor y no en mi cliente??

no hay alguna forma que desde el cliente se agregue el headers y no de error

Comment: Puedes deshabilitar CORS en Chrome en tu máquina local, pero no funcionará en otros equipos. La única solución definitiva es arreglarlo en el servidor. Si quieres deshabilitarlo en local, aquí lo explican (en inglés) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: Es un problema de servidor, NO de cliente